# Gettinf Xml Serialization error when returning XMlDocument from WCF service

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization

i have a WCF Service Method which returns XMlDocument  i have added the attribut [XmlSerializerFormat]
on the method

Is there any way i can return XmlDocuemnt Object from WCf service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the XmlDocument returned from my WCF Service in the following way.

My WCF service looks as shown below:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface ISampleService
    {               
        [OperationContract]
        Test GetXmlData();
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        public Test GetXmlData()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"C:\SampleResponse.xml");

            return new Test() {Doc = doc};
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Test
    {
        public XmlDocument Doc { get; set; }
    }
```

The client adds a reference to the WCF Service and then calls the method GetXmlData() which returns a object Test which has the XmlDocuemnt within it.